# How do you keep input and design in the same line without it cutting out to the next line?

Tags: batch-file

So i'm creating a batch file, that displays your directory and thats just one feature but anyways, you'll directory is going to change while in the batch file, and the therefore the directory text is going to change...

So here's an example of what it does...

```
|----------------------------------|
|>>C:\Users\Joel\..................|
|----------------------------------|
```

When you change your directory it looks like:

```
|----------------------------------|
|>> C:\Users\Joel\Desktop\.................|
|----------------------------------|
```

How do I make it so it takes how ever many letters than takes it away from the spaces?

Please help?

Comment: You sure "design" is something you should try to do in a simple batch file...?

Comment: Well it's batch designing... So it's just a menu, but it displays the directory.

Comment: The text directory such as "%cd%".

Comment: Batch designing... uh-huh

Answer (score 2):

You want to pad a string to a fixed length. The simple strategy is to create a variable containing your string plus more than enough pad characters to reach your limit. Then use a substring operation to trim the string to the desired length. I modified the algorithm slightly to preserve the entire string if it is already greater than or equal to the desired length.

```
@echo off

:: Initialize
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set maxLen=50
set "pad="
set "div="
for /l %%N in (1 1 %maxLen%) do (
  set "pad=!pad!."
  set "div=!div!-"
)
set "div=|!div!|"

:: Test the display
pushd "c:\Users\Joel"
call :displayCurrentDirectory
pushd "c:\Users\Joel\Desktop"
call :displayCurrentDirectory
exit /b

:displayCurrentDirectory
setlocal
set "txt=>>!cd!\"
if "!txt:~%maxLen%,1!" equ "" (
  set "txt=!txt!!pad!"
  set "txt=!txt:~0,%maxLen%!"
)
echo !div!
echo ^|!txt!^|
echo !div!
echo(
exit /b
```

Here is a version that uses multiple lines of fixed width to force the string to fit within the alloted horizontal space.

```
@echo off

:: Initialize
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set maxLen=15
set "pad="
set "div="
for /l %%N in (1 1 %maxLen%) do (
  set "pad=!pad!."
  set "div=!div!-"
)
set "div=|!div!|"

:: Test the display
pushd "c:\Users\Joel"
call :displayCurrentDirectory
pushd "c:\Users\Joel\Desktop"
call :displayCurrentDirectory
exit /b

:displayCurrentDirectory
setlocal
echo !div!
set "txt=>>!cd!\"
:loop
if "!txt:~0,%maxLen%!" neq "!txt!" (
  echo ^|!txt:~0,%maxLen%!^|
  set "txt=!txt:~%maxLen%!"
  goto :loop
)
set "txt=!txt!!pad!"
set "txt=!txt:~0,%maxLen%!"
echo ^|!txt!^|
echo !div!
echo(
exit /b
```

Take a look at [Improved :Format, new :FormatVar and :FormatColor functions](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4027)
 for a more general purpose routine to format text. It allows left and right justification of text.